# Translation of "Hoy hace mucho calor" in another way

Tags: traducción, modismos

> Hoy hace mucho calor.

I see that the translation for it is

> Today is very hot.

But I think that sentence is very complex and difficult to language learners like me. So can we simply write

> Hoy está mucho calor.

Comment: "Calor" is not used with the "to be" verb but the "to have". So "hoy está mucho calor" does not make any sense. This is like "I am 20 years old": in Spanish is not "to be" but "to have", so it is said "tengo 20 años".

Comment: Its more fun when new speakers say things like "estoy caliente".  Try that one on next time dancing at the club gets you sweaty.

Comment: Or "Do you have any eggs today?" at the supermarket

Comment: @paqogomez I have a Venezuelan female friend and one day she asked me how I was, and I innocently said "¡Estoy bueno!".  She told me what I was really saying.  But now, every time I see her I say the same thing to her.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: no.

When learning a new language, you need to resist the urge to translate your language's idioms directly into the new language. Sometimes it's possible, but often it simply does not work. *Hace calor* is how Spanish speakers describe the weather when it is hot.

Answer (score 6):

You must use `hace calor`

You can't micromanage a target language like that,.. "..that's just too confusing, I'll say it this way"

`Está` would not improve your sentence nor would it be considered to mean the same thing.  In fact, it is **grammatically incorrect**

> Hoy está mucho calor

`Calor` is a noun, which means heat.  So you would effectively be saying...

> Today is very heat.

Answer (score 2):

Your direct translation is not completely accurate. "*Today is very hot*" literally means

> Hoy está muy caluroso.

Since a direct translation of "*Hoy hace mucho calor*" should be "*Today there is very much heat*" (obviously wrong), your attitude as a translator should be such that indicates by Kent Anderson in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Hoy está mucho calor" is completely wrong. Alternatively you can use:

> Está haciendo mucho calor. (*)
>
> Está siendo un día muy caluroso.

(En estas dos frases, el gerundio hace innecesario especificar que se  refieren a «hoy», y por tanto se suele omitir.)

> Hoy es un día muy caluroso.

But this is my preferred expression:

> ¡Ozú, que caló!

(This is Andalusian dialect, but any Spanish-speaking knows what it mean`;)`)

(*)  *Note that  "mucha calor" is also correct. (you can use "la calor"  o "el calor").*

Comment: Dear down-voter, my native language is Spanish,  so apart from my deficient English, can you explain  what is wrong in this answer?

Comment: As an aside, it is important to note that *calor* can be feminine only when it refers to the weather. It is always masculine for the physical magnitude or any figurative meaning (such as *calor humano*).

Comment: @Gorpik, Completamente de acuerdo. No era así en el pasado, pero  la forma masculina con el tiempo se convirtió en la «forma culta» y la femenina ha quedado como un arcaísmo para hablar de la temperatura ambiente y sólo en singular (la misma persona que diría  «la calor del verano»  nunca diría «las calores del verano»), pero sigue siendo muy utilizada, y no sólo en América como he leído en algún sitio. No obstante, casi todas las medidas físicas son masculinas («los gramos», «los litros», «los voltios» ...) pero las unidades de energía térmica son siempre  «las calorías».

Answer (score 0):

> Hoy está mucho calor.

This is incorrect in Spanish, however the correct way of writing it would be:

> Hoy está haciendo mucho calor.

in a sentence like this it is inferred that the weather is making the heat, not the day.

Comment: "the weather is making the heat"?

Comment: sorry english is not my first language, but that would be the literal translation. It is correct in spanish tho.